# java CMS including the following features

Tags: java, content-management-system

We are looking for a CMS with following features in mind.

- java based to ease our portal integration
- Wysiwyg editor inside browser
- struts "inside"
- no source code publication mandatory after integration

We would like to know what the community here would recommend.
Thks in advance

Answer (score 0):

how about Alfresco? http://alfresco.com/
I have worked with it in the past, works pretty well once it is installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Liferay](http://liferay.com). Java based but it's more than CMS. It's a portal.